# How to adjust line wrap formatting rules in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, format

I can't remember what it is called, as I am new to java, but I want to know where to find this in the Eclipse formatter. In my getBookData method, I want the stuff after the comma not start a new line.

```
package input;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ReadFile {

    public static Object[] currentBookData;

    public static void getBookData() throws IOException {
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("C:/test.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset())) { // I want the stuff after the comma to be on the same line.
            currentBookData = stream.toArray();
        } 

        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate:

```
"Window -> Preferences -> Java ->Code Style -> Formatter".
```

Adjust the existing template or create/import new one and use the same.

To change the max line width, select a profile and then navigate:

```
"Edit -> Line Wrapping"
```

and set a desired character length in "Maximum Line Width" field e.g. "100".

Comment: @CaffeineToCode Go to Edit -> Line Wrapping" and set a desired character length in "Maximum Line Width" e.g. "100".